# Confusion about SQLite3 on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm learning Rails and I know this might be a silly question. But when it comes to query the database from command line by running the command `rails db`, it yield an error:

```
Couldn't find database client: sqlite3. Check your $PATH and try again.
```

I checked if SQLite3 installed by typing `sqlite3` on the terminal and it said that:

```
The program 'sqlite3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

The thing is I'm following the Rails guide and doing just fine. I have the gem `sqlite3` installed and the application can save, update and delete without any problem. As I know, the sqlite3 gem is just a Ruby interface that work with SQLite3 engine. If I haven't installed SQLite3 yet, how could my application save data?

Apologize for my english.

Comment: I was reading to find out the answer [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database). Didn't see anything.. But lots of good points are made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite3 gem needs the sqlite3 library (& development headers) installed. It does not however need the command line sqlite3 utility.

On some distributions those are all packaged together, but not always. For example on Ubuntu the command line client is provided by the sqlite3 package, but the library by libsqlite3 so it is quite possible to install the library without installing the command line utility

Comment: Thank very much. It seems right. I checked and found that `libsqlite3-dev` already installed. `rails db` worked right away after installing `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the development headers for SQLite3 installed.

For example:

On Ubuntu, you can use

```
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

On Mac with homebrew installed:

```
brew install sqlite.
```

OR

You can use your database like `Postgres` or `MySql`.

Example for `Postgres`:

In Gemfile file

```
gem 'pg'
```

config/database.yml

```
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: project_development
pool: 5
username: "POSTGRES-USER"
password: "POSTGRES-PASSWORD"
```

Comment: The OP asked something else.. -- *If I haven't installed SQLite3 yet, how could my application save data?*